# express passing params to route throws TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm building an architecture for my first express application. One of its part is the authentication service using passport. I'm struggling  with this annoying problem described below.

In my server `app.js` file I have

```
var routes = require('./router/index')(app, passport);
```

`passport` is my passport object configured with 'local-login' `LocalStrategy`. I want to pass this object to my router index and then to my signin route.

In my `/router/index.js` I have

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    app.use('/signin', require('./routes/route.signin')(passport));
};
```

and in `/router/routes/route.signin.js` I have

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    module.exports = function(passport) {

        console.log(passport)

        router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
                            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
                            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
                            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
                        })
        )
    }
```

The `console.log(passport)` logs my passport object, however this code gives me an error:

```
/myapp/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:438
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a
            ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (/myapp/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:438:13)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.use (/myapp/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:436:13)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/myapp/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:187:21)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at EventEmitter.use (/myapp/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:184:7)
    at module.exports (/myapp/server/router/index.js:12:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/server/app.js:28:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Here are my dependencies from `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.10.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "express": "~4.10.6",
    "express-session": "^1.10.1",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.21",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "passport": "^0.2.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
}
```

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your exported function in `/router/routes/route.signin.js` is not returning a middleware function or request handler (or *anything* for that matter, which is why you get `undefined`).

So try this instead in `/router/routes/route.signin.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(passport) {

    router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
                        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
                        failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
                        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
                    })
    )

    return router; // <--- add this
}
```

Comment: So simple :) Your answer solves my problem. Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

`router.use` or `app.use` is expecting a function with the `(req, res, next)` - length of 3 or `(err, req, res, next)` - length of 4, and is getting a function with `(passport)` - length of 1

Something like...

```
module.exports = function(passport) {

  return passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
  });

}
```

or...

```
module.exports = function(passport) {

  return function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', {
      successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
      failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
      failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    })(req, res, next);
  }

}
```

is what you want.